# Phalcon Component using a Custom View (Volt) - how to create Phalcon UI Widgets

Tags: model-view-controller, phalcon

On my website i have to write a number of custom UI components and stays independently to the Controllers and Models, to generate views (In common some people call them UI-widgets).

i.e Creating re-usable "site-search" widget.

Currently, my approach is, I create an extended Component under the "Phalcon\Mvc\User\Component"

```
use Phalcon\Mvc\User\Component as Component;
class SiteSearch extends Component
{
   function doSomething (){
     //how to call a custom view for this component?
   }
}
```

However, I am confused about how we can integrate a view for this extended "Component"? Any idea or different approach we can use?

Answer (score -1):

You can use partials, and reuse it in places where needed.

https://docs.phalcon.io/4.0/en/views#partials

Comment: I know about partial views, how do you call a partial view from a component?

Comment: Then try to use Simple View. https://docs.phalcon.io/4.0/ru-ru/views#simple-rendering